# Alternative of using boolean=?

Tags: racket

The course I'm taking currently won't allow us to use the predicate boolean=? in our assignments and concept checks and says that there is an easier way to get the same result. I still don't get how to get to that result with the information we were just taught (and or not operators). How do make an alternative to boolean=?

Comment: If `b` is a boolean expression, `(bool=? b #t)` is the same as `b`, and `(bool=? b #f)` is the same as `(not b)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative:

```
(define (bool=? x y)
  (or (and x y)
      (and (not x) (not y))))
```

Or ... you could use `equal?`.

Comment: The particular concept check I'm on doesn't allow the use of equal?, cond, boolean=?, false?, if, eq?, boolean->string   It also doesn't allow us to use true or false within the function, which is why I'm confused as to what I can do.

Comment: Link to the restrictions? Otherwise ask the instructor.

Comment: They restricted those deliberately because want the entire code to be made of "and", "or", "not", "=" and other predicates such as number? and boolean?   The question is:                                     Write a function general-true? that consumes a single value x that can be of any type. The function produces true if x is either the Boolean true or the integer 1 and false for all other values. Use only the Boolean operations and, or, and not, the function =, and any type predicates you need.

Comment: This answer only uses or, and, and not. So that’s within the restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Considering this comment from other answer

*The question is: Write a function general-true? that consumes a single value x that can be of any type. The function produces true if x is either the Boolean true or the integer 1 and false for all other values. Use only the Boolean operations and, or, and not, the function =, and any type predicates you need.*

maybe you need this:

```
(define (general-true? x)
  (or (and (boolean? x) x)
      (and (integer? x) (= x 1))))
```

Examples:

```
> (general-true? #true)
#t
> (general-true? 1)
#t
> (general-true? 0)
#f
> (general-true? #false)
#f
> (general-true? '(1 2 3 4))
#f
```